# Updating price programmatically

Tags: magento

I am trying to update several products that are fed from an XML file using:

```
 $productid = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getIdBySku($url->product);
 echo 'Loaded Product: ' . $url->product;

 // Initiate product model
 $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
 $product->setPrice($url->price);

 try 
 {
    $product->save();
        echo "Save / Updated"."\r\n";
  }
  catch (Exception $ex) {
        echo "<pre>".$ex."</pre>";
  }
```

The problem I'm getting a SQL error:

```
exception 'Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Exception' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]:
Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '531-0-82-1.0000-0'
```

The product with the ID of 531 does exist in my db, all I'm wanting to do is update it's price.

What could be causing this?

Comment: Mage is trying to insert, you need to get it to do an update if the product already exists.

Comment: I gathered that. Is there an easy way to `update`? I've only ever seen $product->setXX $product->save()

Comment: Never used Mage, but it is open source. Read the class for an update method, or modify the set method to perform an insert or update SQL query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it seemed to not like the fact I had tiered prices on that product.

Cleared them, re-indexed, re-created tiered pricing, all seems good

Answer (score 1):

Try this to update

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
```

change to

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productid);
```

You have to load a product to update its attributes.